# BigQuery Get all the new Rows Inserted in Table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We had a job which insert the data into our big query table every hour, we want to import this new data to other data sources like MYSQL . Is there any way via which we can find out all the new rows which are inserted in our table.

Comment: Does the job only loads INSERTS operation or the job also does updates, deletes?

Comment: @BihagKashikar
It's only INSERTS

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you consider

[Change history](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/change-history) feature in BigQuery. this will give you the change type (INSERTS) and change_timestamp. Using the change timestamp you can derive the logic find window of period to push new rows to other sources like mysql. Note, this is currently not GA. hope this helps

Comment: What about the cost ? Are these queries consumed higher slots ?

Comment: thinking out logically here, the feature allows tracking what changes have been made to the table and only processing the changes will actually help reducing costly full scans on tables and hence less costs

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to add a default column (with `current_timestamp()` as default value) in your table and to request the data based on that default column

It's pretty similar to Bihag answer, but based on an explicit field, and not on the time travel feature.

---

According to your use case, it's possible that easiest solutions exist. For instance, if you insert the data in a specific partition (of today for instance) and you have only one insert performed in that partition, a simple query over the partition is enough.

Comment: Is there any way via which we can get this data using `load_id` i.e BQ logs, since we are not sure in which partition the data is written ?

Comment: No, you don't have that information in the logs.